# Tabbing into an input element causes default browser scroll to go to wrong area

Tags: html, css

I've built a sidebar and tabbing through items in the sidebar works fine until you tab into the input box.

When you tab into the input box, the browser scrolls way past the input box.

Also it only seems to happen on smaller resolutions / common laptop resolutions. I can't seem to reproduce this on a large desktop monitor.

Why does the browser scroll to the wrong area when you tab into the input box?

The code and reproducible bug may be viewed here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/iUsJSQs4LL8YVs4luDRX?p=preview

Steps:

1. Click on the Plunker link to open the demo site
2. Open up Dev Tools, and toggle device mode (the phone icon in dev tools in the  top left corner)
3. In device mode, select Apple Ipad 3/4 for the device
4. Click anywhere on the yellow sidebar to give it focus
5. Press tab to tab into the textarea
6. Press tab to advance to the next
   textarea
7. Press tab to advance to the input box, notice the browser
   scrolls way off target
8. Press tab to advance to the save button,
   notice the browser scrolls to the correct position

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="section"></div>
        <div class="section"></div>
        <div class="section"></div>
        <div class="section">
          <textarea></textarea>
          <textarea></textarea>
          <label>TEST</label>
          <input value="3">
          <button>SAVE</button>
        </div>
        <div class="section"></div>
        <div class="section"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
.sidebar {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 278px;
}

.section {
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Edit: 
I'm using Chrome Version 40.0.2214.94 (64-bit) on OSX 10.9.5 on a macbook pro 15" 2014 at the default retina resolution.

Here is a screen capture of the problem I am seeing:
(Not enough reputation to paste image inline so I've uploaded it for viewing)

http://minus.com/i/Y52LYpU6SveE

Comment: Firefox here, can't see anything wrong (except the fact that the form is way down the page, about on the middle of the sidebar). It scrolls to where the input is.

Comment: Mac FF, no issues seen. Chrome, the whole block is in the middle vertically in the yellow, on ff it is at the bottom. but no issues when tabbing

Comment: Works fine here in Chrome.

Comment: Linux FF and Chrome, no problem at all.

Comment: This works fine for me on:

    Chrome,  Firefox,  Internet Explorer,  Opera,     Safari, All on windows 7 PC Laptop.

What device and OS are you running this on and getting your negative effects?

Have you tried using tabindex in your inputs to order them and to ensure focus is on them (I think this is an unlikely solution, but the only one I can think at present).

Comment: Have you tried using `tabindex`?

Comment: The weird thing is that the input gets focus but the scroll bar goes way past the location of the input. The tabbing sequence seems correct, it's just the browser's auto scrolling behavior that seems funky. I've updated the question with a link to a screen capture showing the problem. It only seems to be present at lower resolutions.

Comment: @Rick can you try tabbing to the input and then type something to make sure the focus is actually on the input.

Comment: @Huangism focus is on input, interesting that when I tab to the input the scroll area goes past the input, but as soon as I type something it brings the input back into view. I've also updated the original question with steps to reproduce the issue in chrome on any monitor resolution.

Comment: @Rick yes if you type in the input, the browser will bring it into view, this is expected. Just checked on Version 40.0.2214.94 (64-bit) chrome on macbook pro, I cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: I take that back, I was running chrome on my external monitor. When I move the chrome window back to the mac screen using the latest chrome. I CAN reproduce your issue. Perhaps you can try it on a non-retina machine and see if it happens. No idea on cause

Comment: @Huangism I'm able to reproduce the issue on an external monitor by using dev tool's device mode in ipad 3/4 emulation. Also the issue only seems to occur on Chrome, not Safari, so at this point I'm thinking it may be a bug with Chrome.